# character pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a doubt regarding character pointers in c++. Whenever we create a character pointer in c++: `char *p="How are you doing"`, *p should contain the address of memory location which holds the value "how are you doing".*

However, I am perplexed at a sample code and the output. Why `cout<<p` gives back the entire string? It should give value of a memory address. Secondly, why does `cout<<*p` gives only first character of the string?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

const char *str = "how are you\n";
int i[]={1,2,3};


 cout << str << endl;   // << is defined on char *.
 cout << i << endl;
 cout << *str << endl;

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
how are you

0xbfac1eb0

h
```

Comment: If "cout << charPointer" would print out the pointer, then another Frustrated Coder would ask how he could print out a character array and why "cout << charPointer" just doesn't do this...

Comment: Note that C++ has its own (and much more advanced) string support nowadays. The "character pointer as a string" is a C concept which is still useful for C++ code interfacing with C code, but should mostly be avoided in C++ code for your own sanity's sake.

Comment: @stefaanv you can print a character array using derefrencing operator!

Comment: @Frustated Coder: that could be done, but as your question example shows: it doesn't. The dereference of a pointer to a char is a char, not a string.

Comment: oh but i can use *(str+i) where i will be put in a for loop!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to Operator overloading.

the **<<** operator is overloaded to output the string pointed to by the character pointer.

Similarly, with *p, you will get the first character, hence you get the first character as output.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to print the address, then you've to cast the `char*` to `void*`, as

```
const char *str = "how are you\n"; 
cout << (void*) str << endl;
```

In the absense of the cast, `cout` sees `str` as `const char*` (which in fact it is) and so `cout` thinks you intend to print the null-terminated char string!

Think : if you want `coud << str` to print the address, how would you print the string itself?

--

Anyway here is more detail explanation:

`operator<<` is overloaded for `char*` as well as `void*` :

```
//first overload : free standing function
basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr, const char *_Val);

//second overload : a member of basic_ostream<>
_Myt& operator<<(const void *_Val);
```

In the absence of the cast, first overload gets called, but when you cast to `void*`, second overload gets called!

Comment: why doesnt char* p p doesnt contain value of address? Pointer is supposed to carry the address right?

Comment: @Frustrated: That is because there is a special overload of `operator<<` for `char *`, and that interprets a `char *` as a zero-terminated string.

Answer (score 2):

The `cout << str << endl;` prints "how are you", because `str` is `char *`, which is treated as a string.

The `cout << i << endl;` prints 0xbfac1eb0, because `i` is a `int []`, which is treated as `int*`, which is treated as `void*`, which is a pointer.

The `cout << *str << endl' prints "h"` because `*str` is a `char` with value of 'h'.

Answer (score 1):

A C string is just a bunch of bytes, terminated by a null byte (that's a convention). You can also think of it as an array of bytes/characters. If you do `char *str = "foobar";` the compiler reserves some memory for these bytes, and then assigns the memory location *of the first byte/character* to `str`.

So if you dereference the pointer `str`, you get the byte at that location which happens to be the first character of your string. If you do `*(str + 1)` you get the second one, which is the exact same thing as writing `str[1]`.