# Strange pointer behaviour with chars

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, char

I was playing around with structures and their pointers when I observed a strange behaviour. In the following code I made a structure containing: id, last_name_inital, full_name and first_name_inital. Looking at the memory addresses of the int and string works fine but looking at the chars gives broken output. I added to chars outside the structure which show the same behaviour. Looking at just a char output and it's pointer output gives the same char back so no address.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct entry
{
    int id = 1;
    char last_name_inital = 'S';
    string full_name = "August Smith";
    char first_name_inital = 'A';
};

int main()
{
    entry aug;
    entry *p_aug = &aug;
    
    char alpha ='A';
    char *p_alpha = &alpha;

    char sirra ='S';
    char *p_sirra = &sirra;
    
    cout << "Printing structure address" << endl;
    cout << p_aug << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    
    cout << "Printing id and it's address" << endl;
    cout << p_aug->id << " " << aug.id << endl;
    cout << &p_aug->id << " " << &aug.id << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    
    cout << "Printing last_name_inital and it's address" << endl;
    cout << p_aug->last_name_inital <<" "<< aug.last_name_inital << endl;
    cout <<&p_aug->last_name_inital<<" "<< &aug.last_name_inital << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Printing full_name and it's address" << endl;
    cout << p_aug->full_name << " " << aug.full_name << endl;
    cout << &p_aug->full_name << " " << &aug.full_name << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Printing first_name_inital and it's address" << endl;
    cout << p_aug->first_name_inital <<" "<<aug.first_name_inital<< endl;
    cout <<&p_aug->first_name_inital<<" "<<&aug.first_name_inital<< endl;
    cout << "\n";
    
    cout << "Printing alpha and it's address" << endl;
    cout << *p_alpha << " " << alpha << endl;
    cout << p_alpha << " " << &alpha << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Printing sirra and it's address" << endl;
    cout << *p_sirra << " " << sirra << endl;
    cout << p_sirra << " " << &sirra << endl;
    cout << "\n";


}
```

which gives the following output (compiled and written with geany, g++, linux):

> Printing structure address
>
> 0x7fff01772360
>
> Printing id and it's address
>
> 1 1
>
> 0x7fff01772360 0x7fff01772360
>
> Printing full_name and it's address
>
> S S
>
> S S
>
> Printing last_name_inital and it's address
>
> August Smith August Smith
>
> 0x7fff01772368 0x7fff01772368
>
> Printing last_name_inital and it's address
>
> A A
>
> A@ A@
>
> Printing alpha and it's address
>
> A A
>
> AS`#w� AS`#w�
>
> Printing alpha and it's address
>
> S S
>
> S`#w� S`#w�

on every run the last output changes, so obviously something is changing.
An online search gave only this question, which sort of touches the same background but not really or I don't get it. [character pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270277/character-pointers-in-c)

Basically my main questions are what is happening there and is it possible to output a char pointer, so where it is stored?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:**

The quick responses solve the question of how to print out the pointer address of a char. By using:`(void*)(&char_name)`

However it leaves me wondering why the `cout` values of the normal chars change but the values of the chars inside the structure stay the same on rerun. Especially also because the behaviour for the `char 'S'` in the structure with `cout` is the mentioned operator-overloaded-just-give-back-the-char-itself but not for `'A'` and also not for the normal chars outside the structure.

Can anyone explain those differences? Or even does this not occur for you?

Comment: You don't define sirra and p_sirra, and in the quoted output line wrapping is butchered and text doesn't match the code. Please take more care with quoting.

Comment: If have been playing around with chars even more. From structs, classes and normal and the output of the `&a_char` with very peculiar, unexpected output. It seems to readout all the characters it kind find even after the initial one and even if they are not chars any more, which produces the weird output. Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could cast the `char *` to a `void *`. The problem is, that the `operator<<` is overloaded to read `char *` as c_string.

```
cout << "Printing last_name_inital and it's address" << endl;
cout << p_aug->last_name_inital <<" "<< aug.last_name_inital << endl;
cout << (void*)(&p_aug->last_name_inital) <<" "<< (void*)(&aug.last_name_inital) << endl;
cout << "\n";
```

Comment: could you give some example code for `char example = 'A'` how can I now view where it's saved, so it's pointer

Comment: `cout << "example contains" << example << endl; cout << "address of example is" << (void*)(&example) << endl;`

Comment: please include your example code in the answer, so it's easier to find for other people looking at the question

Answer (score 0):

`ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);` is to write sequence of `char` not address, cast to `void*` to get address.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, addresses vary between program executions because the operating system happens to have different memory locations available or deliberately shuffles around data for security reasons.

Inspecting pointer values is only useful for comparing pointers in the same program instance: for example, `p_aug` and `&aug` have the same value.

Comment: Your first part is clear and makes sense, I was just wondering because it's not a real address. The question I have from the second part is: so does p_aug or &aug store the hexvalue for the location and `cout <<` is just not the way to print it?